# Prepare parameter for super constructor

Tags: java, constructor, super

I have a base class that have to be constructed with parameter. In child class I need to prepare this parameter before constructing base class but in Java super must be called before anything else. What's the best way to handle this situation (see simple example below).

```
class BaseClass {
    protected String preparedParam;

    public BaseClass(String preparedParam) {
        this.param = param;
    }
}

class ChildClass {

    public ChildClass (Map<String, Object> params) {
        // need to work with params and prepare param for super constructor
        super(param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create an ***static*** method, that does the transformation and call that.

```
class ChildClass {

    static String preprocessParams(Map<String, Object> params) {
        ...
        return someString;
    }

    public BaseClass(Map<String, Object> params) {
        super(preprocessParams(params));
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `BaseClass` be `ChildClass` here?

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach:

```
class ChildClass {
    public ChildClass(Map<String, Object> params) {
        super(process(params));
    }

    private static String process(Map<String, Object> params) {
         // work with params here to prepare param for super constructor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

because of many parameters that have to be prepared/initialized is simple [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) better solution for me. It's little bit clearer solution at my point of view. Anyway thanks all for answers.

```
class BaseClass {
  protected Object preparedParam;

  public BaseClass(Object preparedParam) {
    this.preparedParam = preparedParam;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

  private ChildClass(Object preparedParam) {
    super(preparedParam);
  }

  public static ChildClass createChildClass(Map<String, Object> params) {
    Object param1 = params.get("param1");

    // prepare params here

    ChildClass result = new ChildClass(param1);

    // do other stuff

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, the super constructor takes a value but the super class has no method to get back the object that you passed in. If this is the case, and you need that object in the super class as well as in yout own code, then the factory method is a solution, while the static prepare method is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would rate Roman's answer as the best so far. 
If the parent class provides a default constructor, you can instantiate an object of super and then use the setter method.